# Python Request; logging in to DVWA

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, python-requests

I'm trying to log in to the Damn Vulnerable Web Application, because I try to write my first exploit. However the first barrier is the login page. Without a valid login I can't access the other directories.

I tried to analyze which headers etc. I have to send, but I still can't seem to make the login work.

```
POST /dvwa/login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.26.129
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.26.129/dvwa/login.php
Cookie: security=high; PHPSESSID=c4bb8820be21ea83e6545eff0a2cb53b
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 44

username=admin&password=password&Login=Login
```

This is the whole request from burp, when I try to log in using the browser.

```
import requests

payload = {
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'password',
    'Login': 'Login'
}

headers = {
    'Host': '192.168.26.129',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
    'Accept': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'http://192.168.26.129/dvwa/login.php',
    'Connection': 'close',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': '44'
}

cookies = dict(security='high', PHPSESSID='c4bb8820be21ea83e6545eff0a2cb53b')

with requests.Session() as c:
    p = c.post('http://192.168.26.129/dvwa/login.php', headers=headers, data=payload, cookies=cookies)
    print(p)
    r = c.get('http://192.168.26.129/dvwa/vulnerabilities/exec')
    print(r.text)
```

And that's how I tried to log in using python requests.
I get a 200 OK twice, but it always returns the HTML code of the login screen.

Could someone tell me what my mistake is?

Answer (score 3):

If you have valid cookies you can add them to your session,

```
cookies = dict(security='high', PHPSESSID='o9m7jgcspe02h9rffj9g7cv0t5')

with requests.Session() as c:
    c.cookies.update(cookies)
```

and now you can access `/dvwa/vulnerabilities/exec`.

---

If you don't have cookies then you can use the login page to get them.
In the login form there is token in a hidden input field that you have to submit. You can get its value with [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or `re`.

```
import requests
import re


payload = {
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'password',
    'Login': 'Login'
}

with requests.Session() as c:
    r = c.get('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php')
    token = re.search("user_token'\s*value='(.*?)'", r.text).group(1)
    payload['user_token'] = token

    p = c.post('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php', data=payload)
    r = c.get('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/exec')
    print(r.text)
```

I'm using `re` because it's a standard library, but it's best to use `bs4` for html parsing. If you have `bs4` installed you can get the token with this selector: `'input[name=user_token]'`.

Answer (score 0):

When using docker, make sure you first create the database

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through this (I actually did it with Ansible, but the steps are the same). When you first access login.php it will give you a user_token in the body text, as mentioned above, and 2 cookie values, PHPSESSID and security. You need to submit all of these to log in. Then you can continue to use the cookie values in subsequent requests.

So the steps are:

1. GET request /DVWA/login.php
2. Get the user_token as described above
3. Get the Cookie values.
4. Create a headers dict with "Cookie" set to the value just obtained.
5. POST request with the body containing username, password, Login=Login, user_token AND the headers with Cookie. (this is the important bit, you must use this cookie obtained from the first access of the login page).
6. Check the returned content contains the text "Welcome to Damn Vulnerable Web Application" to make sure you got it right and you didn't get returned to the login page.

The main difference between the answer above is that you need to do:

```
p = c.post('http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php', cookies=cookies, data=payload)
```

Here's a python solution:

```py
import requests
dvwa_ip = "192.168.1.86"
resp = requests.get(f"http://{dvwa_ip}/DVWA/login.php")
print(resp.text)

# Get the session id from cookies
phpsessid = resp.cookies.get('PHPSESSID')

# Find the html containing user_token in the page text
user_token_html = [x for x in resp.text.split('\n') if 'user_token' in x]
user_token = [x for x in user_token_html[0].split(' ') if 'value' in x]
# user_token is now ["value='2fc5744b8190bae45673e6b91b825178'"], get value using exec
value=''
exec(user_token[0])

# manually set security low as this defaults to impossible
cookies_json = {
    'PHPSESSID': phpsessid,
    'security': 'low'
}
body = {
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'password',
    'Login': 'Login',
    'user_token': value
}

post_resp = requests.post(f"http://{dvwa_ip}/DVWA/login.php", data=body, cookies=cookies_json)
print(post_resp.text) # prints out the "logged in" page (actually index.php)
print("OK") if "Welcome to Damn Vulnerable Web Application" in post_resp.text else print("ERROR")
```

For completeness here's my Ansible solution:

```yaml
- name: "Browse to DVWA login screen to get the user_token from the content and the cookies"
  uri:
    url: "http://{{dvwa_ip}}/DVWA/login.php"
    return_content: yes
    method: GET
  register: login_form

# Get the user_token from the page content - ugly but works
- set_fact:
    user_token: "{{ login_form.content.split(\"name='user_token'\")[1].split('/>')[0].split('=')[1].replace(\"'\",'').replace(' ','') }}"

- name: Show user_token
  debug:
    var: user_token

- name: "Login to DVWA {{ dvwa_ip }} using the username, password, Login, user_token and the Cookie"
  uri:
    # index.php will redirect to login.php
    url: "http://{{dvwa_ip}}/DVWA/login.php"
    return_content: yes
    follow_redirects: all
    method: POST
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    body:
      username: admin
      password: password
      Login: Login
      user_token: "{{ user_token }}"
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{ login_form.cookies_string }}"
    status_code: [ 200, 302 ]
  register: login
  failed_when: "'Welcome to Damn Vulnerable Web Application!' is not in login.content"

- name: "Do SQL Injection"
  command: "sqlmap -u \"http://{{ dvwa_ip }}/DVWA/vulnerabilities/sqli_blind/?id=2&Submit=Submit#\" --cookie=\"{{ login_form.cookies_string }}\" --dbs --batch --flush-session"
  ignore_errors: true
  register: sqlmap_output
```